# Calling ngOnInit twice by getting the dossier id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a anuglar 8 application. And I have a parent child route relationship for creating a new item. But when the page is loaded where you can create a new item. the id of the parent component is first set, but the second time when it comes in ngOninit it is null.

So this is the route relationship:

```
{
    path: ':dossierId',   

    component: ViewComponent, children: [
    {  path: 'item/new/:dossierItemType', component: ItemComponent}
    ],
    resolve: {
      dossier: DossierResolver,
      dossierItems: DossierItemsResolver
    }

  },
```

and this is the ite.component.ts:

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  itemTypes = DossierItemTypeDto;
  formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
  isNew = false;
  editItemForm: FormGroup;
  dossierItemId: string;
  item: DossierItemDto;
  dossierItems: DossierItemDto[];
  dossier: DossierDto;
  globalErrors: ValidationErrors;

  constructor(
    private dossierService: DossierService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private errorProcessor: ErrorProcessor
  ) {
    //this.dossier.id = this.route.snapshot.params.dossierId;
    this.dossier = this.route.snapshot.data.dossier;
    this.dossierItemId = this.route.snapshot.params.dossierItemId;
    this.isNew = this.dossierItemId === undefined;
    this.dossierItems = this.route.snapshot.data.dossierItems;

    if (this.isNew) {
      this.item = {
        title: '',
        itemType: this.route.snapshot.params.dossierItemType,
        date: moment().format('Y-MM-DD'),
        createdAt: moment().format('Y-MM-DD'),
        body: ''
      };
    } else {
      this.item = this.dossierItems.find(i => i.id === this.dossierItemId);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
     this.dossier.id = params.dossierId;
    });

}
```

So when I first look at this line:

I see the id:

```
06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea
```

but when I debug in google chrome, it goes again in the ngOninit and then the id is null.

this is the url:

```
http://localhost:4200/en/dossier/06637e72-8915-4735-9400-4ef7705194ea/item/new/Interview
```

And I get this error:

```
core.js:6406 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (item.component.ts:58)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

then I get even more errors:

```
Interview:9 GET https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
Interview:10 GET https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
core.js:6406 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (item.component.ts:58)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:81)
    at BehaviorSubject.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at ItemComponent.ngOnInit (item.component.ts:57)
```

So the second time params is like this:

```
this.dossier.id = params.dossierId;
```

```
dossierItemType: "Interview"
```

this is the save method:

```
 save(): void {
    const form = this.editItemForm;

    const dossierItemDto: DossierItemPostDto = {
      title: form.controls.title.value,
      itemType: form.controls.itemType.value,
      date: (form.controls.date.value as moment.Moment).format('Y-MM-DD'),
      body: form.controls.body.value
    };

    form.disable();

    if (!this.isNew) {
      this.dossierService.updateDossierItemById(this.dossier.id, this.item.id, dossierItemDto).subscribe(
        item => {
          this.item = item;
          this.sortDossierItems();
          form.enable();
          form.markAsPristine();
          this.errorProcessor.openSuccessSnackBar($localize`Item is saved`);
        },
        error => this.handleError(error)
      );
    } else {
      this.dossierService.newDossierItem(this.dossier.id, dossierItemDto).subscribe(
        item => {
          this.item = item;
          this.dossierItems.unshift(item);
          this.sortDossierItems();
          this.isNew = false;
          form.enable();
          form.markAsPristine();
          this.errorProcessor.openSuccessSnackBar($localize`Item is saved`);
        },
        error => this.handleError(error)
      );
    }
  }
```

```
  this.dossierService.newDossierItem(this.dossier.id,
```

this is now also undefined

this error:

```
core.js:6406 ERROR Error: Required parameter dossierId was null or undefined when calling newDossierItem.
    at DossierService.newDossierItem (dossier.service.ts:359)
    at ItemComponent.save (item.component.ts:97)
```

Because A item is connected with a dossierId

Comment: Can you provide a Stackblitz that showcases the issue?
`this.dossier.id = this.route.snapshot.params.dossierId;` should get you the same result, no?

Comment: Yes, the same result

Comment: Somebody any advice? Thank you

Comment: Check what the value of `this.route.snapshot.data.dossier;` returns. My guess is this is undefined and therefore you have no attribute id under `this.dossier`

Comment: Ye,oke:  this.dossier = this.route.snapshot.data.dossier; indeed this.dossiers is undefined. but I mean and then...?

Comment: If it is undefined it has no attribute id - this is what the error is telling you. You could try assigning it to a blank object for example `this.dossier = {}`. This way you can add the attribute `id` and assign your id value to it. I think something like this would work for you - `this.dossier = this.route.snapshot.data.dossier || {};`

Comment: HI Sam, oke, thank you. But then the problem is that for actually creating a new item. dossier.id is also null. So I cant create a new item. I updated the post

Comment: @Sam. So how can I improve this?

Comment: Has somebody any advice?

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```